# How to delete contacts from mobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I'm working in a project with Salseforce Marketing Cloud. I want to delete contacts from MobileConnect but I don't find a way to do this. I have asked the support and he told me that we couldn't do this, but I need to delete test contacts, contacts with wrong information...etc. Is there any one who has already done this ? Any help will be so much appreciated, even with documentation, totriels or just explaination.

Any help will be so much appreciated. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way to delete Contacts from Marketing Cloud coming with a new release on 26th of January, 2018.

Here's a link to the official documentation - [Contact Delete for Email and MobileConnect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2018_contact_builder_app.htm&type=5)